# How to use videojs-airplay plugin in react?

Tags: reactjs, plugins, video.js, airplay

I'm trying to use videojs airplay plugin in my react project.

I found this repository and tried to import them like this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-airplay

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/videojs-airplay@1.1.1/dist/videojs.airplay.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/videojs-airplay@1.1.1/dist/videojs.airplay.min.css">
```

This is my current react code

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const videoJsOptions = {
      autoplay: false,
      playbackRates: [0.5, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 2],
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      controls: true,
      sources: [
        {
          src: '//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4',
          type: 'video/mp4',
        },
      ],
      plugins: {
        airplayButton: {}
      }
    };
    this.player = videojs(this.refVideoPlayer, videoJsOptions, this.onPlayerReady)
  }
```

But I faced this error

> Error: plugin airplayButton does not exist

I can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Hey, have got the answer ?